# Javascript windows.location, skipping

Tags: javascript, location, alert

I have been having a strange problem with an external javascript file function skipping over windows.location. my program was supposed to take in information from forms then create validate it and after it was validated send it to a php file with get.

I simplified my code to look like

```
function validation(){
 var alerting;//receives from forms commented out
alerting="";
var url="phpadd.php";//after this i would validate it and create the alert but all of that is commented out and irrelevant
if(alerting==""||alerting==null)
   {
   windows.location=url;
   }
   else
   {
   alert(alerting);
   }
}
```

and it didn't work.

Here is the real funny thing 
when I include an alert at the end after windows.location it calls the php file. When I don't it doesn't.
for instance

```
function validation(){
 var alerting;//receives from forms commented out
alerting="";
var url="phpadd.php";//after this i would validate it and create the alert but all of that is commented out and irrelevant
if(alerting==""||alerting==null)
   {//I also create the code here to put values In the url but I commented them all out so this is my effective code.
   windows.location=url;
   alert(url);
   }
   else
   {
   alert(alerting);
   }
}
```

works but it has to print out the alert first. On the other hand when I don't have an alert after the windows.location call It doesn't work at all.(and I know it works with the alert because It is then redirected to the php file which I know works too). 
It doesn't have to be alert(url) either It could be alert anything really. in fact it did work with a while(1) loop done afterward but almost crashed the browser first. It's like it is leaving the function before it does what it is supposed to and forgetting about it.

I have tried it in firefox and in google chrome without either way working.

also if you can't find a way to do this. if you could give me a way to take in values from a form to javascript and then send valid values to a php file without windows.location(i've tried every other variant I have found also like: windows.location.href location.href location.assign(url))
I would appreciate it.

by the way The code I left out is not causing the problem because it is commented out where it doesn't work and in the one where it works that is irrelevant because it works it just puts up an alert I don't want.

Comment: sorry That was a mistake of me typing it into the site when I put it in my code I did use window.location. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling

```
window.location = url;
```

not

```
windows.location = url;
```